# PDF to HTML conversion using aspose.PDF java library ?

Tags: java, html, pdf, aspose

I am using poppler for pdf to html conversion in my project. Is there any other third party plugins which can convert the given PDF document to html and improve the quality of conversion ? can we achieve the pdf to html conversion using apose.PDF java library ?

Answer (score 2):

Check out [JPedal](http://www.idrsolutions.com/pdf-to-html5-conversion/), it is able to convert PDF to HTML. I recently had to use it for another usecase, the results were pretty good. It handles embedded fonts very well. Unfortunately it is not free.

Another great (free) PDF library is [IcePDF](http://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CC4QFjAA&url=http://www.icesoft.org/java/projects/ICEpdf/&ei=ECFlUtXUKsrWtQaWyYDgBA&usg=AFQjCNFUMUwcKf89smIhp8q4yCRXHqC94g&bvm=bv.54934254,d.bGE), it is free but afaik it only can extract text/images or render the PDF to an image, but with really handsome results.

Answer (score 1):

check out [pdfBox](http://pdfbox.apache.org/)
 if you want a opensource one.It gives good extraction tools .I build for extracting text and images until now,And working nicely.